# check multiple variable in one conditional statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the first `if ... else` statement to check both `a` and `b` simultaneously. And I want an efficient way of counting no_of_good and no_of_poor in order to minimize the number of lines of code. Is it possible?

How can I print both `a` and `b` as good in if statement? And also how to calculate good and poor count?

```
a = 1  
b = 3  
good_count=0  
poor_count=0  
if a in range(0,6) and b in range(0,6):   
    //print and count
elif a in range(6,10) and b in range(6,10):  
    //pprint and count
```

This is a long method of doing the work:

```
a = 1  
b = 3  
good_count=0  
poor_count=0  
if a in range(0,6):  
    print("a = GOOD")
    good_count+=1`    
elif a in range(6,10):
    print("a = POOR")
    poor_count+=1
if b in range(0,6):    
    print("b = GOOD") 
    good_count+=1 
elif b in range(6,10):   
    print("b = POOR ")  
    poor_count+=1
print("no_of_good=",good_count," ","no_of_poor=",poor_count)
```

Actual output:

```
a = GOOD  
b = GOOD  
no_of_good= 2   no_of_poor= 0
```

Expected output should also be same but by using any different method

Comment: Does your shorter method not work? What is the issue you are having?

Comment: "*efficient*" and "*minimize the number of lines of code*" are not necessarily the same thing - one-liners are often inefficient.

Comment: If you don't care about the `name` of the variables, you can just use a list, like my answer below!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to repeat your if statements then you could look into having a datatstructure to hold your values and iterate over all the values.

I also changed the condition to use integer comparisson instead of a range; it seames cleaner in my opinion.

Here is an example using a `dict` to hold the data:

```
data = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 3,
    'c': 5,
    'd': 6,
}

good_count = 0
poor_count = 0
for k, v in data.items():
    if 0 <= v <= 5:
        good_count += 1
        result = 'GOOD'
    else:
        poor_count += 1
        result = 'POOR'
    print('{} = {}'.format(k, result))

print('no_of_good = {}'.format(good_count))
print('no_of_poor = {}'.format(poor_count))
```

And this is the output:

```
a = GOOD
b = GOOD
c = GOOD
d = POOR
no_of_good = 3
no_of_poor = 1
```

Does that help you?

Comment: yeah it helped. i want to ask if there is a variable already holding a value e.g.  
 avg_sen_len = (word_count/sen_count).  and the value for this variable constantly changes as the text changes. how can we add it into the dict.

Comment: You could update the `dict` like this: `data['avg_sen_len'] = word_count / sen_count`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the variables, `a,b,c,d` etc, you can just use a list, and use the index of the lis t to print `GOOD` or `POOR`

```
li = [1,3,5,6]

good_count = 0
poor_count = 0

#Iterate through the list
for idx, item in enumerate(li):

    #Check the condition on the item and print accordingly
    if 0 <= item <= 5:
        good_count+=1
        print('index {} = GOOD'.format(idx))
    elif 6<= item <= 10:
        poor_count+=1
        print('index {} = POOR'.format(idx))

#Print final good and poor count
print('no_of_good = {}'.format(good_count))
print('no_of_poor = {}'.format(poor_count))
```

The output will be as below:

```
index 0 = GOOD
index 1 = GOOD
index 2 = GOOD
index 3 = POOR
no_of_good = 3
no_of_poor = 1
```

Comment: here the list contain variable values li={1,3,5,6} but i don't care about the "variable values" NOT "variables". because the values are changing each time you run the code SO i can only specify the variables a,b,c,d in the list. Does it follow the same procedure?  also i don't want to print index 0 = good. instead a OR b OR c OR d = GOOD (what ever variable name at that index)

Comment: Yes, change the list when you want to change the values, also you will run out of variable names once you list grows bigger, hence it is better to have a dynamically generated variable name, does a name like var_0 or var_1 work for you? @Mis_Sid